# Uilabel in uitableview not showing opaque without transparency in debug simulator color blended layers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

Heres my code , cant find how this is happening. for the lbl_nombre its is ok. but the lbl_desc i get the output as being with a transparency channel on the sim color layers enabled.

-- EDIT -- I did another check because in code everything looked fine, and know how its happening, but this shouldnt make this happen, whenever the description has a word with an accent such as á ó í it is happening, for other words such as ñ from the latin language is acting ok.. so how come uilabel will turn the alpha channel / transparency if i set it using any accents ? any fix for this ?
-- EDIT -- included MenuViewCell

```
class MenuViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lbl_nombre : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lbl_desc : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lbl_precio : UILabel!

}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



  let data = self.sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
  let cell : MenuViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MenuViewCell




    cell.lbl_desc.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.lbl_nombre.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.lbl_nombre.text = data.name
    cell.lbl_desc.text = data.desc
    cell.lbl_desc.isOpaque = true
    cell.lbl_desc.backgroundColor = .white

    var finalprice = ""
    if (data.price > 0){
        finalprice = "RD$\(data.price!)"
    }
    cell.lbl_precio.text = "\(finalprice)" as String
       cell.lbl_nombre.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell.lbl_desc.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

    cell.lbl_nombre.sizeToFit()
    cell.lbl_desc.sizeToFit()


    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show `MenuViewCell`? I think the problem is because of something below the label

Comment: @trungduc thanks so much for reaching out, i thought there was something with the code too but.. now i have tested some more. the problem relys as soon as some incoming text has an í, especifically.  i just tested it manually without the data setting from json, the í is giving me the trouble..  cell.lbl_desc.text = "hola prueba \n multiline í \n ok" // data.desc

Comment: @trungduc edited and added the menuViewCell.  Also double checked on the storyboard, (3 labels)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is because of `í` character. It's strange.

Comment: yup. this is so annoying.. tripled checked.. ó no problems. í Boom chaos.. its happening to me on ios 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem, you should set `layer.masksToBounds` of label to `true`.

```
cell.lbl_desc.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it did work! . do you know by any change how to make the  disclosureDetail icon opaque by any chance ? :D without having to set a custom view for the accesorytype of the cell..

Comment: Do you mean change opaque of disclosureDetail icon? Or remove color blended layer on it

Comment: remove color blended layer on it :D

Comment: I think using custom view for `accessoryView` is easiest way. But anyway, color blended layer on `accessoryView` won't affect too much if you keep it :D.